# Scheduled agent in Lotus Notes

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

Since I don't see the option in schedule properties of an agent, I was wondering if it's possible to run an agent once every 3/6 months, or even every year?
I only see -more than once daily,daily,weekly,monthly,never..

Answer (score 2):

Pick the closest option in schedule properties, eg monthly, and then add code at the beginning of your agent that checks the date and depending on the result either exits without doing anything, or continues running the main body of the code. Works fine with agents written in lotusscript, never tried it with @formula.

Comment: can I also use a profile document(form) with a field that contains the count (each month is increased by one)?

Comment: Sure. That has some advantages because you can test by setting the profile. But what if someone runs the agent manually (via a 'tell amgr' command) so it actually runs twice in one month, or many times? If you want to save something in a profile doc, I would save the next date that you want the agent to actually run. If the profile doc is missing, run the agent's main logic and create the profile doc and set the date to today 3 months. Ditto if the profile doc exists and the date is in the past. But if the profile doc exists, and the saved date is still in the future, just terminate the agent.

Comment: Now I have some problems with profile document. If I try to get the value of a field I always end up with an empty string `doc.fieldname(0)`
When I debug it shows that the isProfile is true, so I obviously have the handle to the document. I guess I'm doing something wrong with the profile document.

Comment: Open another question for that. Using comments for discussion off the original topic of question is discouraged on StackOverflow.